# Get start and end of week with the start on Monday and end on Sunday in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

```
    function getStartAndEndOfWeek(date) {

        var curr = date ? new Date(date) : new Date();
        var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); 

        var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(first));
        var lastday = new Date(curr.setDate(firstday.getDate() + 6));

        return [firstday, lastday];

    }
```

I am unable to set the start of week as Monday. Above code gives the firstday as sunday. Also if at all we add first plus one it will give monday as the start but the issue would be where lets say (06/29/2014, sunday) is the input, it should return (06/23/2014 as start and 06/29/2014) as the end. How can we accomplish that? If I add "first + 1" it returns 06/30/2014 as start and 07/06/2014 as end date. Any help? Thanks.

Answer:

```
    function getStartAndEndOfWeek(date) {

        //Calculating the starting point

        var curr = date ? new Date(date) : new Date();
        var first = curr.getDate() - dayOfWeek(curr);

        var firstday, lastday;

        if (first < 1) {
            //Get prev month and year
            var k = new Date(curr.valueOf());
            k.setDate(1);
            k.setMonth(k.getMonth() - 1);
            var prevMonthDays = new Date(k.getFullYear(), (k.getMonth() + 1), 0).getDate();

            first = prevMonthDays - (dayOfWeek(curr) - curr.getDate());
            firstday = new Date(k.setDate(first));
            lastday = new Date(k.setDate(first + 6));
        } else {
            // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
            firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(first));
            lastday = new Date(curr.setDate(first + 6));
        }

        return [firstday, lastday];            
    }

    function dayOfWeek(date, firstDay) {
        var daysOfWeek = {
            sunday: 0,
            monday: 1,
            tuesday: 2,
            wednesday: 3,
            thursday: 4,
            friday: 5,
            saturday: 6,
        };
        firstDay = firstDay || "monday";
        var day = date.getDay() - daysOfWeek[firstDay];
        return (day < 0 ? day + 7 : day);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about making a simple method to allow you to easily manipulate the first day of the week:

```
(function() {
  var original = Date.prototype.getDay;
  var daysOfWeek = {
    sunday: 0,
    monday: 1,
    tuesday: 2,
    wednesday: 3,
    thursday: 4,
    friday: 5,
    saturday: 6,
  };

  Date.prototype.getDay = function(weekBegins) {
    weekBegins = (weekBegins || "sunday").toLowerCase();
    return (original.apply(this) + 7 - daysOfWeek[weekBegins]) % 7;
  };
})();
```

Then you can simply use:

```
var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay("monday"),
    last  = first + 6;
```

Comment: Also the problem is that if I am sending sunday as the date to the function it returns the next week, rather than prev week. Thats the reason I did not add one.

Comment: Updated, does that help?

Comment: I understand the issue with switching months. There is a main issue where lets say today (06/29/2014, sunday) is the input, it should return  (06/23/2014 as start and 06/29/2014) as the end. How can we accomplish that? Now according to what you have told it returns 06/30/2014 as start and 07/06/2014 as end date

Answer (score 24):

You can set first to be the Monday by shifting the result of getDay(), then taking a modulo of the result.

```
var first = curr.getDate() - ((curr.getDay() + 6) % 7);
```

Comment: But this returnes 6 at sunday.

Comment: Yes, and Monday will be 0, as requested.

Answer (score 6):

much simpler

```js
var numberdayweek = [6,0,1,2,3,4,5];
fecha = new Date();
console.log(numberdayweek[fecha.getDay()]);
```

Comment: Could be simplified to `[6,0,1,2,3,4,5][fecha.getDay()]` or even `[6,0,1,2,3,4,5][new Date().getDay()]`

Answer (score 2):

Found other solution:

```js
const getDayIndexMondaySunday = (date) =>date.getDay() === 0 ? 6 : date.getDay() - 1
 // Result on Today
 console.log(getDayIndexMondaySunday(new Date()));
```